# When are the Flutter/JavaScript interoperability functions ready in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flutter

Friends

I have a Flutter/Web project embedded in a another web app.  Once the Flutter code is loaded I wish to call a Flutter function from JavaScript.

To that end I have put code in the generated "index.html" (as described [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/initialization)) to call my function.

My problem is that when the Flutter app has finished loading the JS -> Flutter bridge is not ready.  The function is undefined.  If I wait two seconds, it is defined.

Waiting using a timer is very tacky.  Is there an idiomatic way to detect that setting up the JS/Flutter interface  has finished?

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function (engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function (appRunner) {
    let runAppResult = appRunner.runApp();
    // My code here
    jsToFlutter("123"); // Fails.  `jsToFlutter` undefined
    setTimeout (function () {
      sendDataToFlutter("123"); // Function defined and called
    }, 2000);

    return runAppResult;
      });
    });
```

Naturally I have, in Flutter:

```
@JS('jsToFlutter')
external set jsToFlutterGateWay(void Function(String) f);
:
:
jsToFlutterGateWay = allowInterop(dataFromJS); // Called from main()
:
:
void dataFromJS(String data) async {
// My flutter code to call from JS here
```